# Mod Security to only auditlog critical rule events

Tags: mod-security

Im trying to get mod security 2.7.4 to only audit log when a critical rule match has been found.

I am using Anomaly Scoring, so in the event 1 warning has been matched, do not log the event as it will be allowed. If 2 warnings are matched thus making the score to high, it would trigger the inbound_anomaly_score rule which in turn would deny the request. I would like it to log this event, with the warnings that contributed to the triggering.

Only need it to do it across phase 1 & 2.

Currently using the default value for SecDefaultAction.
These are the current settings for the Audit Log. SecAuditLogRelevantStatus still logs response codes of 200.

```
SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
SecAuditLogRelevantStatus "^(?:5|4\d[^4])"
SecAuditLogType Serial
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.